# Looking for simpler way of dividing 2 numbers A and B where the largest is always the numerator

Tags: python, math

Looking for a short way of doing a division where the large number is always the numerator. Is there a simpler way of doing it other than this?

```
def divide(A, B):
  if A > B:
    return A/B
  else:
    return B/A
```

Comment: What's wrong with this way?

Comment: It can be written shorter with an if-expression but it is questionable if this is simpler.

Comment: Trying to see if there is already some sort of python math function that does something like that.

Comment: There is no specific math function for this in the standard library.

Comment: don't forget to check for 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like `if` statements and you want to avoid redundant comparisons, then you can do this:

```py
from operator import truediv

def divide(a, b):
    return truediv(*sorted([a, b], reverse=True))
```

Or, alright, the slightly less silly way of doing this:

```py
def divide(a, b):
    a, b = sorted([a, b])
    return b / a
```

But... don't. Your way is the simplest, most obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

there is a better way to do so :

```
def divide(A,B):
     return max(A,B)/min(A,B)
```

Comment: Don't think this is better. It's unclearer and will probably require more comparisons that a simple if-else clause.

Comment: in theory the max and min function do the same as an if statement  and I think that a built_in function python is all the time optimized as much as possible . And the max and min function are O(n) time complexity which means that its time of running depends on the number of variables ,but in our case we only have two of them which ; Therefore, it wouldn't take too much time .

Comment: I think what Ted is saying is that your code will compare the two numbers twice (once in `max` and once in `min`), whereas the OP's code only compares them once. The actual performance difference is negligible, of course.

Comment: Totally agree .

Comment: I think this is very clear *and* compact. I like it. Maybe not clearer than OPs original code, but it compares favorably to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some more ways...

The straight-forward one that oddly nobody showed yet:

```
def divide(A, B):
  return A/B if A > B else B/A
```

Short one, if your values are positive:

```
def divide(A, B):
  return max(A/B, B/A)
```

Shorter one, if your values are positive and you know the smaller one divides the larger one:

```
def divide(A, B):
  return A//B or B//A
```